# When I add a module to the backbone part of yolov5, Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu

Tags: pytorch, gpu, tensor

When I white balance the image through cnn prediction parameters, it always shows RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found at least two devices, cuda:0 and cpu! and when I debug the program, it shows RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight [64, 3, 3, 3], but got 2-dimensional input of size [1, 256] instead，The following is my code, which has troubled me for a long time. I hope you can give me some pointers on whether the code is not standardized enough, so that this part of the module is always unable to be sent to the GPU. Thank you.

```
class VE(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c1=3, c2=256, k=3, s=1):
        super(VE, self).__init__()
        # conv_1
        self.conv_1 = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 64, k, s)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU(True)
        self.max_pool_1 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d((3, 3), (2, 2))

        # conv_2
        self.conv_2 = torch.nn.Conv2d(64, 128, k, s)

        self.max_pool_2 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d((3, 3), (2, 2))
        # conv_3
        self.conv_3 = torch.nn.Conv2d(128, 256, k, s)

        self.max_pool_3 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d((3, 3), (2, 2))

        # conv_4
        self.conv_4 = torch.nn.Conv2d(256, 512, k, s)

        self.max_pool_4 = torch.nn.AvgPool2d((3, 3), (2, 2))

        # conv_5
        self.conv_5 = torch.nn.Conv2d(512, 1024, k, s)

        self.adp_pool_5 = torch.nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((1, 1))
        self.linear_proj_5 = torch.nn.Linear(1024, 256)

    def forward(self, x):
        out_x = self.conv_1(x)
        out_x = self.relu(out_x)
        max_pool_1 = self.max_pool_1(out_x)

        out_x = self.conv_2(max_pool_1)
        out_x = self.relu(out_x)
        max_pool_2 = self.max_pool_2(out_x)

        out_x = self.conv_3(max_pool_2)
        out_x = self.relu(out_x)
        max_pool_3 = self.max_pool_3(out_x)

        out_x = self.conv_4(max_pool_3)
        out_x = self.relu(out_x)
        max_pool_4 = self.max_pool_4(out_x)

        out_x = self.conv_5(max_pool_4)

        adp_pool_5 = self.adp_pool_5(out_x)
        linear_pro_5 = self.linear_proj_5(adp_pool_5.view(adp_pool_5.shape[0], -1))

        return linear_pro_5


class gate_module(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c1=256, c2=7):
        super(gate_module, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = VE(3, 256, 3, 1)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(c1, c2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x)
        x = self.linear(x)
        return x


# 对图像进行白平衡处理
class white_balance(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c1=256, c2=3):
        super(white_balance, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = VE(3, 256, 3, 1)
        self.wb = nn.Linear(c1, c2)
        self.Get_gate = gate_module(256, 7)

    def forward(self, x):
        x_out = self.encoder(x)
        wb = self.wb(x_out)
        gate = torch.tanh(self.Get_gate(x_out)) * (1.0 - 0.01) + 1.0
        wb_gate = gate[:, 0]
        wb = torch.exp(torch.tanh(wb) * 0.5 + 0.5)
        color_scaling = 1. / (1e-5 + 0.27 * wb[:, 0] + 0.67 * wb[:, 1] + 0.06 * wb[:, 2])
        wb = color_scaling.unsqueeze(1) * wb
        wb_out = wb.unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(3) * x
        wb_out = (wb_out - wb_out.min()) / (wb_out.max() - wb_out.min())
        wb_out = wb_gate.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(3) * wb_out
        return wb_out


class GetImg(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, c1=3, c2=64, k=3, s=1):
        super(GetImg, self).__init__()
        self.wb_out = white_balance(256, 3)
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(c1, c2, k, s, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x_out = self.wb_out(x)
        x_get = self.conv(x_out)
        return x_get
```

I tried to add .to(device) to the tensor in this module, but it still can't solve the problem, so the problem is not the tensor in the code but the code writing has a problem, so the whole module is not sent to the gpu.